# how to make deb file install other deb files without errors?

Tags: linux, installation, debian, apt, deb

I created a local repository. Than i make a 2 debian files, a batman.deb file that have for dependency base.deb

Control file:

```
Package: batman
Version: 1.0
Architecture: all
Essential: no
Priority: optional
Depends: base
Maintainer: monkeyproduction
Description: test description
```

postinst file:

```
apt-get -f install
```

So i use postinst file to check for dependencies that need to be installed.

The problem is that i get those errors:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
dpkg: error processing package base (--configure):
 installed base package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 100
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of batman:
 batman depends on base; however:
  Package base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package batman (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 base
 batman
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How other installs do it without error? I mean when i try to install some package it says that it needs 10 other dependencies and the installation of them is going without those messages that i get.
How can i fix mine ones and make it clean install without errors?

Answer (score -1):

removed my apt-get -f install

apparently *Depends: base* is the only think that i need to have in my batman.deb control file to download and install base.deb file too